# Android loggin errors for multiple levels of users

Tags: android, logging, multi-user

Hi in android is it possible to log the errors in such a way that there are multiples levels of users who can see them. Say there will be admin who can see all the errors logged and exceptions catched and logged. There will be developer who can see only the programmatic errors or exceptions catched and logged. Is this possible ans any one tell me how this could be done or some example? I am with a project that is in research stage. Please help

Answer (score 0):

well in a logical way it is possible by giving such conditions , that if user is of admin type then allow him for viewing all the logs just like this , the other types & logging can be specify.

Comment: Can you please clarify i could't get you

Comment: in one way you can write logs in separate files . so admin will see all logs. rest user will sees their type logs files.